# Modifying one azure app service restarts another azure app service of same resource group

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have two azure app services A and B in one resource group. On change azure app service A, the azure app service B also restarts. Is it due to them being in same resource group? If not, then is it a glitch in portal?

Comment: that shouldn't be the case - can you check the logs whether Service B was restartet?

Comment: I checked the logs, there is no log in service B that mentions the app was restarted. However, on opening service B's url, it showed that app had gone offline (suddenly) despite not making any change into it.

Comment: As a test, can you try the same in another resource group and check?

Answer (score 2):

It should not be the case. Please try again. Before restarting app service 1, make sure your both app services are accessible and then restart.

Answer (score -1):

Are they both running on the same App Service plan?  If they are and the change you made was to the App Service plan then both Apps would be reinstanced

Comment: better suited as a comment